# Why am I getting an error while running jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to run Jupyter notebook from my Windows command prompt with this command:

```
python -m notebook
```

But I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook_*main*_.py", line 3, in 
> from notebook import notebookapp as app
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 7, in 
> import asyncio
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio_*init*_.py", line 26, in 
> from .queues import *
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 12, in  from .tasks import coroutine
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 329
> fs = {async(f, loop=loop) for f in set(fs)}
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: did you try starting the notebook using `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: This looks like older code is run on a newer Python version (`async` used as function name, it's a keyword now). Make sure your Jupyter is up to date!

Comment: As the other suggest, a jupyter notebook is not a python file. If you open the jupyter file in a text editor you will notice the difference. Save/export the python code from jupyter as .py file in the file/download menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the CLI for this. Instead, you can just click on the Jupiter application where it's available on start menu/ All programs.
After you open you'll see it's loading CLI and automatically opens using your default browser.